# ASP MVC3 - Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created a stock, empty ASP.NET MVC3 project, deployed it to my local machine, and when I pull it up in the browser I see the error below.  This is a project with no code written by me (yet) so I assume it has to do with my environment.  At one point this machine had an old version of ASP.NET MVC installed, but it has since been uninstalled.  Skimming through the project references, every .dll is at v4.0.30319.

> System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.

```
[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +404
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +125
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +704
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +123
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +382
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +233
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Tom

Comment: Do you get this exception if you run the application in Visual Studio's development server? What is the file version of the System.Web.Mvc assembly you are referencing?

Comment: Thanks Darin - yes, just tried it and it does work in the development server, just not in IIS.  Under both servers, the dll version is 3.0.20105.0.  However, in IIS it's being loaded from the GAC, and in the dev server it's being loaded from "NativeImages".  IIS:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll  Dev: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web.Mvc\d96f7e57b756969ce922e83fcf05936d\System.Web.Mvc.ni.dll

Comment: Any idea already? I'm having the same problem!

Comment: Not yet... at least on my machine, MVC3 is DOA.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible IIS does not have the proper Handler Mappings for .cshtml files. Check out [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/237928/problem-running-mvc3-app-in-iis-7)